# Java Native Memory Usage in Java 8 on Heroku

Tags: java, heroku, memory

I'm having problems getting my memory usage under control, and I've exhausted all I know or could find on the web (apparently Google is not with me). Below is a screenshot of Heroku's memory reporting, and as you can see my heap and metaspace are both within my allowed limits. When I run the native memory summary, it shows that my class space is using way more than I'd like, but I can't find anything on how to tune this in Java 8. My application is very small and the GC (I would think) should be freeing the class space way before it gets to the level it's at. Any Ideas?

`JAVA_OPTS` and Heroku metrics page follow:

```
-Xmx128m
-Xss512k
-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=128m
-XX:+UseSerialGC
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=20m
-XX:CompressedClassSpaceSize=20m
-XX:NativeMemoryTracking=detail
-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions
-XX:+PrintNMTStatistics
```

[image: Heroku metrics]

#### UPDATE as requested by @codefinger

Here is my `Procfile`:

```
java $JAVA_OPTS -Dserver.port=$PORT -jar build/libs/*.jar
```

I had `JVM_OPTS` as my environment variable before, but it is consistently `JAVA_OPTS` everywhere in Procfile and environment variables. It was just a typo I made in SO.

#### UPDATE 2 as requested by @codefinger

Here is the output from `jinfo -flag MaxHeapSize 4`:

```
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx300m -Xss512k -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

-XX:MaxHeapSize=134217728
```

#### UPDATE 3 - Additional details from `jcmd 4 VM.native_memory summary`

```
-                 Java Heap (reserved=131072KB, committed=131072KB)
                            (mmap: reserved=131072KB, committed=131072KB)


-                     Class (reserved=94577KB, committed=82673KB)
                            (classes #14554)
                            (malloc=2417KB #12980)

                            (mmap: reserved=92160KB, committed=80256KB)

-                    Thread (reserved=84165KB, committed=84165KB)
                            (thread #37)
                            (stack: reserved=21648KB, committed=21648KB)
                            (malloc=118KB #182)

                            (arena=62399KB #73)

-                      Code (reserved=21880KB, committed=13432KB)
                            (malloc=1080KB #2290)
                            (mmap: reserved=20800KB, committed=12352KB)

-                        GC (reserved=462KB, committed=462KB)
                            (malloc=30KB #314)
                            (mmap: reserved=432KB, committed=432KB)

-                  Compiler (reserved=267KB, committed=267KB)
                            (malloc=136KB #685)
                            (arena=131KB #3)

-                  Internal (reserved=2693KB, committed=2693KB)
                            (malloc=2661KB #17480)

                            (mmap: reserved=32KB, committed=32KB)

-                    Symbol (reserved=19827KB, committed=19827KB)
                            (malloc=16047KB #165359)
                            (arena=3780KB #1)

-    Native Memory Tracking (reserved=3768KB, committed=3768KB)
                            (malloc=496KB #7906)
                            (tracking overhead=3272KB)

-               Arena Chunk (reserved=1189KB, committed=1189KB)
                            (malloc=1189KB)
```

Comment: How certain are you that `JVM_OPTS` is picked up by your Java process? Can you post your `Procfile`?

Comment: Nice catch, @codefinger. I hadn't thought of that, but it looks like it's consistently `JAVA_OPTS` everywhere except when I typed it into SO. Question updated.

Comment: Can you use `heroku ps:exec` to run `jinfo -flag MaxHeapSize PID` and share the output. Might also check `InitialHeapSize`.

Comment: Hi. Did you find a solution? I get the same behavior as you.

Comment: No "real" solution. I ended up moving away from Heroku to a dedicated server that I managed. Not ideal, but I could not in good conscience recommend Heroku for the amount of memory I would have ended up needing for the application to run. Heroku is a microservice platform, not a place for monoliths. Unfortunately, even a relatively small Spring Boot application for me was a "monolith." I ended up on a Linode server with 12G of RAM and it's worked fine ever since.

Answer (score 0):

82 MB of committed Metaspace (which I can see from the `jcmd` output) is pretty typical for a Java app. The JVM has to load all of your classes, frameworks, and libraries into memory.

You could experiment by removing some libraries to see if that lowers non-heap memory.